# count occurence based on three columns in R

Tags: r, filter

I have a data frame

```
chromosome_4    26869907    26895858    .   0.93    +   mRNA    ID=g2108.t2;Parent=g2108;   chromosome_4    26887040    26887102    .   16.4    +   Target  Motif:Helitron-1_Dvir-Dmon-C    5   65  62  g2108
chromosome_4    26869907    26895858    .   0.93    +   intron  ID=g2108.t2;Parent=g2108;   chromosome_4    26887363    26887481    .   17      +   Target  Motif:Helitron-1_Dmon   20  83  118 g2108
chromosome_4    26869907    26895858    .   0.93    +   exon    ID=g2108.t2;Parent=g2108;   chromosome_4    26887528    26887618    .   27.6    +   Target  Motif:Helitron-11_Dmon  507 594 90  g2108
chromosome_4    26869907    26895858    .   0.93    +   gene    ID=g2108.t2;Parent=g2108;   chromosome_4    26887618    26887648    .   18.9    -   Target  Motif:Helitron-2_Dvir-Dmon-C    21  51  30  g2108
chromosome_8    8522721     8540839     .   0.93    +   intron  ID=g2108.t2;Parent=g2108;   chromosome_8    8522721     8540839     .   16.4    +   Target  Motif:Helitron-1_Dvir-Dmon-C    5   65  62  g2108
chromosome_8    8522721     8540839     .   0.93    +   mRNA    ID=g2108.t2;Parent=g2108;   chromosome_8    8522721     8540839     .   17      +   Target  Motif:Helitron-1_Dmon   20  83  118 g608
chromosome_8    8522721     8540839     .   0.93    +   intron  ID=g2108.t2;Parent=g2108;   chromosome_8    8522721     8540839     .   27.6    +   Target  Motif:Helitron-11_Dmon  507 594 90       g608
chromosome_8    8522721     8540839     .   0.93    +   gene    ID=g2108.t2;Parent=g2108;   chromosome_8    8522721     8540839     .   18.9    -   Target  Motif:Helitron-2_Dvir-Dmon-C    21  51  30  g608
```

I want to count motifs (col16) based on chromosme number (col1) and gene part (col7) per unique gene (col20).
I tried this

```
gene1 %>%  filter(V1,V7,V20) %>% select(V16) %>% table
```

the error is

```
Error in `filter()`:

! Problem while computing `..1 = V1`.
x Input `..1` must be a logical vector, not a character.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

at the end I need to be able to bind several such tables belonging to different populations: `bind_rows(gene1, gene2, gene3)`

Comment: `dyplr::filter()` is to select certain observations meeting a condition, not columns. try `group_by()` - for better help, please share your data in a reproducible format, something like `dput(head(gene1, 20))` (for the first 20 observations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what your desired output should be, but if you are looking to count the number of unique motifs in `v16` for a given chromosome, part, and gene, you can use `group_by()` and `summarize()` in the `dplyr` package:

Data

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = rep(paste0("chromasome_", c(4,8)), each = 4),
                 V7 = c("mRNA", "intron","exon","gene"),
                 V16 = c("Motif:Helitron-1_Dvir-Dmon-C",
                         "Motif:Helitron-1_Dmon",
                         "Motif:Helitron-11_Dmon",
                         "Motif:Helitron-2_Dvir-Dmon-C",
                         "Motif:Helitron-2_Dvir-Dmon-C",
                         "Motif:Helitron-1_Dmon",
                         "Motif:Helitron-11_Dmon",
                         "Motif:Helitron-2_Dvir-Dmon-C"),
                 V20 = c(rep(c("g2108","g608"), each = 4)))
```

Code

```
df %>% 
  group_by(V1, V7, V20) %>% 
  summarize(unique_motifs = n_distinct(V16))
```

Output:

```
#   V1           V7     V20   unique_motifs
# 1 chromasome_4 exon   g2108             1
# 2 chromasome_4 gene   g2108             1
# 3 chromasome_4 intron g2108             1
# 4 chromasome_4 mRNA   g2108             1
# 5 chromasome_8 exon   g608              1
# 6 chromasome_8 gene   g608              1
# 7 chromasome_8 intron g608              1
# 8 chromasome_8 mRNA   g608              1
```

Comment: thanks, but why does it give me only one value?!

Comment: In the sample data you provided, there is only one unique motif per group (a group being the same gene, chromosome, and part)

Comment: yeah that's correct, another package was interrupting dplyr for me